# PHP, MySQL, PDO - Insert Into Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have this code:

```
<?php
require_once 'dbconfig.php';

if(isset($_GET['id'])) {
    try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    $getSavedHolidays = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO tvinfo(id, imdbid, name, rating, genre1, genre2, year, plot, uploader, views, downloads, uploaddate, size, resolution, fps, audio) VALUES (:id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id, :id)");
    $getSavedHolidays->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $getSavedHolidays->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));
    $Result = $getSavedHolidays->fetchAll();

    if(!$Result){
        die('Error: ID Not Found');
    }

}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print_r($e->errorInfo);
    die();
}

foreach ($Result as $r) {
    echo 'Name: '.$r['name'].'<br>';
    echo 'Rating: '.$r['rating'].'<br>';
    echo 'IMDB ID: '.$r['imdbid'].'<br>';
    echo 'Genre 1: '.$r['genre1'].'<br>';
    echo 'Genre 2: '.$r['genre2'].'<br>';
    echo 'Year: '.$r['year'].'<br>';
    echo 'Plot: '.$r['plot'].'<br>';
    echo 'Uploader: '.$r['uploader'].'<br>';
    echo 'Views: '.$r['views'].'<br>';
    echo 'Downloads: '.$r['downloads'].'<br>';
    echo 'Uploaded at: '.$r['uploaddate'].'<br>';
    echo 'Size: '.$r['size'].'<br>';
    echo 'Resoution: '.$r['rsolution'].'<br>';
    echo 'FPS: '.$r['fps'].'<br>';
    echo 'Audio: '.$r['audio'].'<br>';
}

}

?>
```

When i go to example.com/file.php?id=Lel it outputs: Array ( [0] => HY093 ) and no error_logs. the tables etc are definitely there.

This code works fine when I use it with a select query to grab some info and output it but when I try inserting it wont work.
Any ideas?

Comment: Really? Like 10x times `:id`, just a quote from the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php): `You must include a` **unique** `parameter marker for each value you wish to pass in to the statement when you call PDOStatement::execute()` ->[unique](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unique)

Comment: Oh very sorry, Ill check to see if it works when its unique

Comment: Ok its workign fine but can i ask how can I get it to like check if the value for IMDBID is already there if its not there then continue but if it is already there then do nothing just die.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set `ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` to true:

```
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, true);
```

then you will be allowed to bind a single time or you will have to do it for each time you have it in the query

Also get rid of  `$Result = $getSavedHolidays->fetchAll();` since you are inserting there is nothing to fetch

To check if the value exist before inserting, you can do:

```
$sql = 'SELECT COUNT(*) from tvinfo WHERE imdbid = :id';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(array(':id' => $_GET['id']));

if($stmt->fetchColumn()){ die('Already exist');}
```

Comment: Should I remove the setfetchmode bit aswell?

Comment: Yes sir remove it no need for that

Comment: Ok, Btw your missing the if()'s {} :P

Comment: Also $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); should be $stmt = $sql->prepare($sql); right? Or am i missing somehting here?

Comment: Lol yeah u get the point! I trust that u good enough to fix typos

Comment: Umm Fixed all typos but im getting: Fatal error: Call to undefined method PDO::fetchColumn() on line 17, I edited the code a small bit to fit my variable names but here it is:
This is line 17:
if(!$sql->fetchColumn()) {
  die('Already exist');
 }

Full script:
http://pastebin.com/VzYTeZQb

Comment: Okay fudn out why, I was meant to link it o the varibale checkIfExists not sql and your not meant to use the opperator ! as that means if its not found then die, So remove the ! operator and it will work perfect. Thanks dude!